# How can I use an IO ports on Digilent Genesys Virtex 5 to drive 6 external leds?

Tags: led, digital-logic, fpga, io

I have a project which requires led output.  Right now I'm using the onboard leds, but I would like to use 6 external LEDs instead.

Which IO pins should I use, and how should this be done?

I'm guessing that it's as simple as finding six output ports, wiring each led in series with a resistor, and connecting each path to ground, and then editing the ucf file to map the entity output port names to the io ports.  Is it that simple?  Will someone give me a detailed explanation?  Thank you.

Comment: Do you need individual control over the LEDs?

Comment: @Ignacio Yes , in my behavioral description in the architecture I control the on-board LEDs individually. So, six different output LEDs, various patterns representing different states.

Comment: Basically, your configurations will work. If your LED can consume large current, you may need a buffer (such as BJTs, or FETs ) to drive them instead of directly drive them using I/O pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Virtex-5 can drive up to 24 mA per I/O pin depending on the selected I/O standard and I/O bank voltage (see DS202, page 7 in [Virtex-5 FPGA Data Sheet - DC and Switching Characteristics](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds202.pdf)). The drive strength can be set in an ucf file.

Example ucf line:

```
NET "ML505_GPIO_LED[0]" ....... IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 DRIVE = 12 SLEW = SLOW;
```

See [Xilinx Constraints Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/cgd.pdf) for more details.

If your LED needs a higher current, then use a FET as suggested by @diverger. You can use the [ML505 Schematics](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ml50x_schematics.pdf) as a reference how Xilinx connected LEDs to the FPGA (see page 10) . This board is equipped with dozens of NDS331N FETs ([N-Channel Logic Level Enhancement Mode FET](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/ND/NDS331N.pdf)) to drive external devices. These FETs provide the currents to drive the LED and also act as voltage level-shifter. So a 1.8V I/O pin can switch a 2.5V LED. Using the NDS331N as a level-shifter for mid-speed data wires - as done on the ML505 board - is not a good solution! (e.g. I²C wires)